# How to do login in Blazor WebAssembly with ASP.NetCore WebAPI?

Tags: api, blazor-webassembly

I want to do a login in my BlazorWebAssembly, without hosted server side, just a standalone client side. I already created a server side with ASP.NET CORE WebAPI. So how can I do the login function, can anyone guide me please. Thank you.

Comment: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/08/13/blazor-webassembly-jwt-authentication-example-tutorial  go through with it, you will get the idea how you can implement authentication in blazor.

Comment: @D.J. thank you, Gratitude